# How to migrate a MySQL server database from an older version to a newer?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a database from an older MySQL server (**v 5.0**) to a newer (**8.0**).

So I exported the dump file from the original database, and tried to import in the newer system, but then it's showing a thousand syntax errors.

The thing is that the older database is working fine, so I presume that the problem is the version. May someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server for a MySQL question? Please correct your tags.

Comment: _"a thousand syntax errors"_ but you haven't listed even one here. In any case, this is better asked on [dba.se]

Comment: Not really sure what help you expect we can provide based on this "question"! The two versions are like 15 years apart, you should treat them as two different products. Get a proper ETL product to migrate the data or address those syntax errors one by one. There is no magic bullet.

Comment: One does not simply go from 5.0 to 8.0. You will need to go from 5.0⇢5.5⇢5.6⇢8.0 

Comment: @matigo you are missing 5.7 :)

Comment: So just to see if i understand correctly, i will need to import this dump file first in the 5.5 , then i will export a new dump file from 5.5 and import in the 5.6 and so on until the 8.0. That's it?

Comment: @Shadow I *think* a 5.6⇢8.0 works without a 5.7-step so long as there aren’t deprecated data types defined in the tables … 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not have old databases to test this with, but for migrations of this type in the past (MySQL 4.x ~ 5.7), I had to follow this process:

1. Create a dump of the database and import it onto another machine, either using the same version or just slightly newer (for example, build a VM or Docker container with MySQL 5.0~5.2 and import)
2. Upgrade the MySQL installation to the next major point release
3. Repeat step 2 until you’re at a more recent, target-compatible version
4. Dump the database
5. Import into the target version
6. Test, test, test, and test

That last point is really important